# Poco::Data binding to an std::array of arguments

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I'm using `Poco version 1.5.2`. I have the below  problem by example, using the `Poco::Data` stuff.

```
 Statement select(mySession) // connect to SqLite session object.
    std::vector<int> args;
    args.push_back(1);
    args.push_back(2);
```

This query does not work and throws below text to the standard output

```
select << "SELECT X,Y,Z FROM my_table WHERE a=? AND b=?", bind(args), into(myEntityContainer),now;
```

> "Invalid access: Can not convert empty value."

However this works fine

```
select << "SELECT X,Y,Z FROM my_table WHERE a=? AND b=?", bind(arg[0]), bind(arg[1]) into(myEntityContainer),now;
```

Is this corrected in later releases?
How can I do a workaround in `version 1.5.2` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this corrected in later releases?

No, this is not trivial to implement because currently `bind()` expects its argument to be bound to a single column (ie. "vertically" - if you bind a vector, then values from the vector will be inserted into a single column).

> How can I do a workaround in version 1.5.2 ?

You have already given a workaround, albeit not a generic one; a generic solution would iterate through the container and "manually" add each member as a binding to the statement, see [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.7.9/Data/testsuite/src/DataTest.cpp#L1337-L1359) for an example (note that `use()` and `bind()` essentially do the same thing, semantical difference between the two explained [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.7.9/Data/include/Poco/Data/Binding.h#L44)).